# How to change a layer-list drawable?

Tags: android, android-drawable

Trying to learn some new things and can't figure this one out, any help is appreciated. Given this simple code which is right from Google's documentation:

layers.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/first_image">
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_red"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/second_image" android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp">
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_green"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/third_image" android:top="20dp" android:left="20dp">
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_blue"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And main.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+myImageView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/layers" />
```

Question: How do I programmatically reference one of the drawables in the layer-list so I can change it to a different drawable?

Thanks.

So now I have my new drawable that I want to swap in in variable `myImage` correct? Now how do I get that into the layer-list? I assume I use `findDrawableByLayerId` and `setDrawableByLayerId`, but how exactly? Or I could be doing it completely wrong! Help!

What am I trying to do? Change the drawable that's displayed. For example suppose I had another drawable called "android_purple", how would I switch it in for the "android_green" drawable in the layer-list example above?

EDIT:

With my limited knowledge here is my code so far (which does *not* work, I get error that `setDrawableByLayerId` is undefined):

```
Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
BitmapDrawable newImage = (BitmapDrawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.android_purple); //Get replacement image, can't use LayerDrawable or get error.   
boolean layer_drawable_changed = (setDrawableByLayerId((R.id.second_image), newImage)); //Set new drawable? Error on this line.
```

Comment: It would be better if you explain a little more elaborately exactly what you want to do ? Then it would be easier to answer your question perfectly.

Comment: Edited question, simply trying to change the drawable in the layer-list to a different drawable. Am I making sense here?

Comment: As far as i know , You can declare all your drawables in a layout-list & can define a state when to chose which drawable. The states can be like focusable state / pressed state / selected state etc etc.

Comment: Well thinking about it a bit I figured out I can use a different layers.xml for every possible combination and just setImageResource to the appropriate layers.xml file and this works fine but I doubt is the best solution?

Comment: I don't think thats the best solution you can do by creating different layout files.Instead,you should change the image resource of an imageview according to some conditions on your class using setImageResource.For example,Say,you have a variable x & you have to change the resource of an imageview according to the value of x.Suppose,if x value is 1 then setImageResource to image1.jpg,if x value is 2 then setImageResource to image2.jpg and thus goes on.I hope you understand what i wanted to say.I just wanted to say that change your image resource according to related conditions , in your class.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> Question: How do I programmatically reference one of the drawables in the layer-list so I can change it to a different drawable?

Here's what I would try:

Step #1: Put `android:id` attributes on the `<item>` elements as illustrated [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)

Step #2: Cast the `getDrawable()` result to a [`LayerDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html)

Step #3: Call `mutate()` if you do not want to affect anyone else using the `Drawable` (may be optional)

Step #4: Call `setDrawableByLayerId()` to set/replace a `Drawable` for a given layer ID

Comment: Thank you. What you are saying is what I'm trying but it's not working. I'm beginning to think it's not possible. The only way I've found to do what I want is to change the ImageView source to an entirely new layers.xml file that contains the drawables I want. If I'm making any sense...

Comment: Updated question with what I'm trying.

Comment: @ShadowGod: Don't use `getApplicationContext()` for GUI-related stuff. That being said, I tend to agree with Junaid, that there may be more effective solutions for what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Ok thanks. As a beginner I just didn't think what I am trying to do would be such a big deal and that hard to accomplish. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Just a final note for other beginners that may be reading this: I have discovered that what I was ultimately trying to do here, layer graphics for a user interface, is easier done with a RelativeLayout nested inside a FrameLayout.

Comment: @ShadowGod: I'm not quite certain why you needed the nesting necessarily, as `RelativeLayout` supports Z-axis ordering on its own. Later children of a `RelativeLayout` stack over top of earlier children. Regardless, I'm glad to hear that you have this working!

Comment: So, you gave up? Bummer! I am trying to do the same thing now; but no matter what I do, the bitmap that is the backmost layer gets removed when I call setDrawableByLayerId.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hello sir one issue in this code if I can make to create the round corner imageView using Layer-list. in this layer-list first is one drawable image and another is roundcorder shape drawable xml file.when I try to use this code according to change the layer drawable work perfect but the rounded drawbable not set proper of the image.

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh: Sorry, but I do not know what you mean. Please ask a fresh Stack Overflow question, providing the code that is giving you problems and screenshots of what you are seeing.

Comment: @CommonsWare sir not any error in code but using this code i can't achieve proper result.

Comment: Calling `mutable()` is important when you use the same layer drawable in multiple places , since the item has same id.

Comment: Possible to center the bitmap you insert.  IE, how can you programmatically do this: <bitmap android:gravity="center">...</>

Comment: @lostintranslation: I do not know, sorry.

Comment: Is it possible to do same thing directly in XML code rather then java

Answer (score 58):

Step 1:Retrieve the Layer-list from the drawable folder: (Mine was called digits at /res/drawable/digits.xml)

```
LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.digits);
```

Step 2: Name the replacing image (not the the image already in layer-list)

```
Drawable replace = (Drawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.replacing_image);
```

Step 3: Replace the Image using the setDrawableByLayerId(int id, Drawable d)  method

```
boolean testfactor = ld.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.first_image, replace);
```

This returns a boolean value that will return false if replacing the image failed

Step 4: Load main Imageview (basically id of layer-list in the actual xml layout code)

```
ImageView layoutlist1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.layout_list1);
```

Step 5: (re)-Set the Imageview with your updated LayerDrawable by saying:

```
layoutlist1.setImageDrawable(ld);
```

RESOURCES: 
I'm a software and mobile app developer.

I looked all over the web and alot of Stackflow.com in order to get to this point. All the answers were like the ones that were already on this page. I was trying to do the same thing. Then I thought about the idea of "updating the image" and came to this.

This **should/can also work** for when you want to put a Bitmap in place of one the items on your list. You just have to use the replace (setDrawableByLayerId) method. to replace on ids. ImageView has a lot of methods.

This was also helpful: [LayerList drawable + conversion to a Bitmap](http://droiddevelop.tumblr.com/post/10121899873/part-98-layerlist-drawable-conversion-to-a-bitmap)

Comment: Thank you [D-R](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1244383/d-r) for help with formatting my response/fixing my link at the bottom. I just joined recently because I wanted to add this response when I was frustrated with the answers available

Comment: is this method a memory hog? i need to set rounded image in a recyclerview