# Change <layer-item> items by Java code

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have the following XML:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/customPlayerProgressBg">
    <shape>
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#FF999999"
                android:endColor="#FF999999"
        />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@+id/customPlayerProgressSecondary">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#FF5C3C68"
                    android:endColor="#FF5C3C68"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/customPlayerProgress"
>
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#FF5C3C68"
                android:endColor="#FF5C3C68"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

I want to change the "customPlayerProgress" and the "customPlayerProgressSecondary" by Java code. How can that be accomplished?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change a layer-list drawable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018435/how-to-change-a-layer-list-drawable)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that you want to have access to them through Java code after they are loaded as a Drawable in your app, you should be able to do something like the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable);
    final ClipDrawable d1 = (ClipDrawable) ld.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.customPlayerProgress);
    final ClipDrawable d2 = (ClipDrawable) ld.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.customPlayerProgressSecondary);

    /* modify ld, d1 and d2 by calling their methods here */
}
```

Also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018435/android-how-to-change-a-layer-list-drawable) for some more ideas.

Comment: Worked. R.id.customPlayerProgress was not being recognized, i had to rebuild the project (Project > Clean, then Build).

Comment: It seems that "getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable)" doesn't return the same object that can be obtained in code. Isn't it better to get LayerDrawable object using "view.getBackground()" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change generated XML files at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

You may be familiar with [DOM](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html). You just need to modify the change and then save the file.

Here is an [article](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-dom.html) that may be of some assistance.