# Change color of shape within layerlist within selector programmatically

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-selector

if a button's background is set to a `shape drawable`, we can programmatically by calling
`(GradientDrawable) findDrawableByd(R.drawable.some_shape).setColor(someColor);`.

If it it set to a `layer-list drawable`, we can achieve changing its color by calling

```
LayerDrawable someLayerList = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.someLayerList);
((GradientDrawable) someLayerList.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.someShape)).setColor(someColor);
```

I want to go one level deeper.  How can I programatically set the color of a shape drawable that resides within a layer-list, that resides within a selector?

Using the code snippet above *sort of* works.  It actually appears very buggy.  I have multiple dialogfragments set up that change the color of the button in sequence.  While the first dialogFragment is always coloured properly, the rest are usually not.  I want to stress the point that when the button's background is set to the layer-list, everything works *perfectly*, if set to the selector, it gets kinda buggy.

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976836/change-layer-item-items-by-java-code