# TouchImageView setImageResource not working

Tags: android, resources, imageview, drawable, touchimageview

I'm using a TouchImageView to display a map with a custom layer depending on a certain condition.The drawable used for the TouchImageView is a LayerDrawable, declared in the xml.

The TouchImageView is declared:

```
    <com.example.app.TouchImageView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:src="@drawable/layer"
  android:id="@+id/map"/>
```

The drawable is a LayerDrawable:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bgverkenning3" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blauwpng2" />
    </layer-list>
```

This works fine, but as soon as I try to set it, all I get is a white screen. I've tried to set it using setImageResource. setImageDrawable doens't work as well.

```
    map = (TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setImageResource(R.drawable.layerenergie);
```

Tried it and it doesn't work:

```
    LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable)map.getDrawable();
    ld.setDrawableByLayerId(1, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blauwpng2));
   map.setImageDrawable(ld);
```

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018435/android-how-to-change-a-layer-list-drawable

Comment: Already tried that, but if I understand it correctly that doesn't work as well.