# Change background image of drawable resource

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, xml-drawable

Basically I created a **background.xml** to add the background image to preserve the aspect ratio. Then I set the background of the `ImageView` to `@drawable/background`.

How could I change the background image from the Activity?

In activity_main.xml:

```
<ImageView
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:src="@drawable/gradient"/>
```

In background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

`@drawable/image` is the actual .jpg file

Comment: Why you have a background.xml? Just set `android:background="@drawable/image` in ImageView can work

Comment: http://spearhend.blogspot.in/2012/04/load-android-drawable-from-xml.html see if this works.

Comment: why **android:background**?? i bet you mean **android:src**???

Comment: @EllieZou I did it this way because using @drawable/image straight screws up the aspect ration of the image. Do you know a way to preserve the aspect ratio of the background image?

Comment: @pskink I did it this way because I want a gradient over the image. so the src is the drawable gradient

Comment: no no no, **don't** do that, in that case use `setImageDrawable()` with a `LayerDrawable`

Comment: @pskink thats a pretty good suggestion. Sounds like it would work. Let me try it out.

Comment: @Orane Did you ever try `android:scaleType`?

Comment: @pskink why is it wrong to set images on the background?

Comment: @IvoBeckers because it doesn't keep aspect ratio well

Comment: @EllieZou `android:scaleType` only applies to the foreground image. Im trying to change the background image. @pskink had something with the `<layer-list>` but I still need to figure out how to change an individual image. Im going to try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018435/android-how-to-change-a-layer-list-drawable

Answer (score 0):

You can just set imageview programmatically like this

```
ImageView image;
//initialization
image.setImageResource(int);
```

// where int is resource like R.drawable.something