# create following code xml programmatically into layerlist android

Tags: android, android-drawable, layer-list, android-shape, android-shapedrawable

I have to set background of this to many views with different colors. but if I make it so, the xml will be around 20 files, which is huge, so I want to convert the following xml `layer-list` into progmatical way into fully independent module without even a single xml, so that it can be reusable, please help me guys.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    //i can create this drawable
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff2632"/>
        </shape> </item>

    //I don't know how to achieve this one, especially this "bottom property"
    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#d7ffa2"/>
        </shape> </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Which color you want to change?

Comment: @NigamPatro,<item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#d7ffa2"/>
        </shape> </item>

Comment: @NigamPatro,basically i have to set this xml as background to may views with different color codes

Comment: Mean, the bottom part?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - How to change a layer-list drawable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018435/android-how-to-change-a-layer-list-drawable)

Comment: @Rami, buddy i want to create this as programatically not to create this xml

Comment: @VikramSingh You can create *1* xml file and change it programatically depending on your needs (instead of creating 20 files).

Comment: @Rami, i don't also want to create that one, i want it to be fully independent and through programatic way

Comment: @Rami, and thanks for the feedback

Comment: @VikramSingh in this case, you need to create a custom class that extand from drawable and pass your parameters in the constructor.

Comment: @Rami, i know how to create the drawable programatically but i don't know how to achieve this "<item android:bottom="2dp"> "

Comment: Please find the answer and let me know for issues...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please find the below code,

```
// This is the first item in your XML file
GradientDrawable layer1 = new GradientDrawable();
layer1.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
layer1.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ff2632"));

// This is your second item in your XML file
GradientDrawable layer2 = new GradientDrawable();
layer2.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
layer2.setColor(Color.parseColor("#d7ffa2"));

// This will give the bottom space which you are unable to do    
InsetDrawable insetLayer2 = new InsetDrawable(layer2, 0, 0, 0, 2);

// This is the final drawable which is to be used
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{layer1, insetLayer2});
```

Refer this, and let me know for issues.

Comment: buddy where u had used the ,<item android:bottom="2dp"> property

Comment: The `insetLayer2` is doing this task.

Comment: would you explain the above in detail, so that i can understand

Comment: Which part you are unable to understand? Please go through the comments.

Comment: new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{layer1, insetLayer2});

Comment: Here we need to pass the drawable which we want in a layered manner.

Comment: means we can pass as many drawable instance as we want like  upto 10 theny what we the order of appearance??

Comment: That depends on you, like here if you pass the insetLayer2 as first item, layer1 as second item, then the whole drawable will be of layer1 color.