# Load image into layer-list programatically

Tags: android

I'm trying to load an image into a layer-list programatically. I found some solutions but somehow it does not work. Here is what I did:

layer_list.xml: (Set as background of RelativeLayout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/red" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/replace"
        android:drawable="@drawable/placeholder" />
    <item
        android:bottom="-250dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="-250dp"
        android:top="250dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-10"
            android:pivotX="0%"
            android:pivotY="100%">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Code to load bitmap into layer-list:

```
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.layer_list, null);
layerDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.replace, drawable);
```

But somehow the placeholder image is never replaced with the new bitmap. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: This is how I load the image:

```
    private void loadImageIntoLayerList(Context context, String url) {
    // To get image using Fresco
    ImageRequest imageRequest = ImageRequestBuilder
            .newBuilderWithSource(Uri.parse(url))
            .setProgressiveRenderingEnabled(true)
            .build();

    ImagePipeline imagePipeline = Fresco.getImagePipeline();
    DataSource<CloseableReference<CloseableImage>> dataSource = imagePipeline
            .fetchDecodedImage(imageRequest, context);

    BaseBitmapDataSubscriber dataSubscriber = new BaseBitmapDataSubscriber() {
        @Override
        public void onNewResultImpl(@Nullable Bitmap bitmap) {
            // You can use the bitmap in only limited ways
            // No need to do any cleanup.
            if (bitmap != null) {
                Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp);
                LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) ResourcesCompat.getDrawable
                        (getResources(), R.drawable.layer_list, null);
                if (layerDrawable != null) {
                    layerDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.cover_image, drawable);
                    header.setBackground(layerDrawable);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailureImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
            // No cleanup required here.
        }
    };
    dataSource.subscribe(dataSubscriber, CallerThreadExecutor.getInstance());
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018435/how-to-change-a-layer-list-drawable  Have you taken a look at this post?

Comment: And maybe replace android:drawable="@drawable/placeholder" with <bitmap android:src=“@drawable/icon”/> and in your code, replace bitmap with: layerDrawable.draw(new Canvas(bitmap))

Comment: Tried both, drawable still not being replaced...

Comment: Modify your last line as boolean check = layerDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.replace, drawable); to see if there is an issue with that part of the code

Comment: When logging check it's returning nothing.

Comment: By nothing, you mean null? Or maybe it's not getting called. Have you tried debugging that line?

Comment: I did debug it and it seems to find the layoutlist and the bitmap and drawable is correct as well...

Comment: I'll try to reproduce the same situation on my project. I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: Debugger also shows me that after layerDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId() the layerDrawables second child has the correct bitmap in it but UI is still showing the old one. Although mWidth and mHeight is -1 in debugger.

Comment: Issue seems to be the RelativeLayout. If you can use an ImageView for the background, everything works fine.

Comment: So replace the RelativeLayout with an imageview and dont set a source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line at the end:

```
myRelativeLayout.setBackground(layerDrawable);
```

Looks like you need to set the background once again after changing the drawable.

Here is the working code:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    final RelativeLayout RL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RL);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.image7, null);
            LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.layer_list, null);
            layerDrawable.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.replace, drawable);
            RL.setBackground(layerDrawable);

        }
    });
}
}
```

layer_list.xml is the same as yours, only with different drawables. activity_test.xml is simply a RelativeLayout with a button in middle.

Comment: How did you name your drawable "layer-list"? You are not allowed to use "-" in names. Maybe that is your problem? Because I'm using the same code as yours, with a drawable named "layer_list" and mine is working right now. How do you call this image replacement code?

Comment: It's a name with underscores, no dashes. And I'm using the Fresco image pipeline to get a bitmap out of an image url and in the callback i do the image replacement.

Comment: So first try something simpler: add a plain RelativeLayout on your screen and simply change its background with the bitmap you've recieved. If that's working, then your bitmap is fine. I'll edit my answer with the working code I have, so you can modify it to solve the issue.

Comment: I added the code for the image loading and replacement

Comment: Never used Fresco, so can't help any further. Just note that my working code started working once I re-set the background. So try working around that. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the Bitmap you get in `BaseBitmapDataSubscriber.onNewResultImpl(Bitmap)` for this.
If you take a look at the [Javadoc](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/df2854a76786f58e044a71617309cc3c0a0c358c/imagepipeline/src/main/java/com/facebook/imagepipeline/datasource/BaseBitmapDataSubscriber.java#L74) for this method, you see that the Bitmap's memory will be freed shortly after.

It would be better if you would use `SimpleDraweeView` directly in your layout. It supports overlays, backgrounds and a placeholder, so it handles everything for you.
You can split up your layer list in separate drawables, e.g. a background and an overlay and set it in XML or in code.
Then you can just do `draweeView.setImageURI(...)` to load your image.

You can also [implement a custom view](http://frescolib.org/docs/writing-custom-views.html) for this to get the drawable (and set it as a background for example since you can get the Drawable itself with `Drawable drawable = mDraweeHolder.getTopLevelDrawable();` according to the custom view guide).

If you really have to use the imagepipeline directly, you also have to handle the lifecycle of the Bitmap correctly. You get a `CloseableReference` for the bitmap and you have to manually release it.
Take a look at http://frescolib.org/docs/using-image-pipeline.html for more information. You can also take a look at classes like [PipelineDraweeController](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/fc57c147380de732db61799880f6a7ceaa080aff/drawee-backends/drawee-pipeline/src/main/java/com/facebook/drawee/backends/pipeline/PipelineDraweeController.java) and [AbstractDraweeController](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/679c1cccccb80d6760acfa55033824e2093fa620/drawee/src/main/java/com/facebook/drawee/controller/AbstractDraweeController.java) to see how this could be implemented (that's what happens when you use SimpleDraweeView).