# What is the best way to create a circular ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I know there are many third party libraries to create a CircularImageView available but I got to know all of them are not very efficient (some do not support animations/transitions, some have performance issues).

1. I need to create a screen similiar to the Whatsapp Contacts screen (A list with circular ImageView and some text).
2. Need to load data in the list online.
3. I don't want to crop image or create a bitmap copy (like this- [How to Make an ImageView in Circular Shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378741/how-to-make-an-imageview-in-circular-shape))
4. Need to have touch feedback (ripple effect) on clicking the circular image

Can I achieve this without any third party library? If not please let me know the best way to do this.

Comment: try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278821/how-to-round-an-image-with-glide-library

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22105820/5110595)

Comment: Without any third party you have to manage memory cause of converting images to bitmap and this isn't fair to spend time to handle many issues on converting images to circle image

Comment: Thanks @FarshidABZ I understand this. Could you suggest me a library that you have used and satisfies my requirements without any performance issues?

Comment: Try loading images from url using Picasso and made them circluar with circle transform like this https://gist.github.com/julianshen/5829333
It also helps you loading same image next time more fast as it manage image cache.

Comment: If you are using glide to load the images then with glide you can create circuler image

Comment: Thanks @Hemant. But can I load an image dynamically into a layer list?

Comment: @WijaySharma yes, have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159263/load-image-into-layer-list-programatically)

Comment: i code this : 

 LayerDrawable shape = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_btn_rating_star_off_mtrl_alpha);
        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),R.drawable.abc_btn_rating_star_on_mtrl_alpha);
        shape.setDrawable(0,drawable);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the next [library](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView). Add `Gradle` dependency:

```
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
```

Then simply add `XML` view:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use glide for both purpose load image and circular image.

For glide : `compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'`

```
Glide.with(context).load(your url).asBitmap().centerCrop().dontAnimate().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_card_view).error(R.drawable.placeholder_card_view).into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(imageView) {
                @Override
                protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                    RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                            RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), resource);
                    circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks... so no need to customize the imageview? Will this always center crop the image?

Comment: @WijaySharma Yes just take a simple image view for this. it will always center crop the image.

Comment: @WijaySharma for ripple effect you can try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34128965/8089770