# How to add a image to drawable xml in android

Tags: android

I have a drawable xml file which draws a circle.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">

<solid

    android:color="#666666" />

<size
    android:width="120dp"
    android:height="120dp" />
</shape>
```

now, I have to add a image in drawable folder. please help me where to change the code.

Comment: I have to add a background image and one image in a same xml file

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a layer list like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item>
       <shape android:shape="oval">
           <solid
               android:color="#666666"/>

           <size
               android:width="120dp"
               android:height="120dp"/>
       </shape>
   </item>

   <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_drawable"/>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify this drawable from an activity to change the image?

Comment: @PabloR. I think your are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018435/how-to-change-a-layer-list-drawable

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks François.

Comment: @Francois in my case i have drawable which is vector home icon when i tried above solution circle shape is smaller and home icon looks bigger, how to solve it?