# How to add image (jpg) in xml

Tags: android, xml, image, android-studio, drawable

How to create a round drawable xml which contain image. When i add color then its works good but if i add image then only show image on view.

[image]

I wanna to create random color view same as other round view.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"><item>
<bitmap android:src="@drawable/background"/>
<shape>
    <corners android:radius="100dp"/>
</shape></item></selector>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a image to drawable xml in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235388/how-to-add-a-image-to-drawable-xml-in-android)

Comment: I also try this.. but not work in my condition