# changing drawable alpha programmatically inside layer list

Tags: android, xml

[How to change a layer-list drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018435/how-to-change-a-layer-list-drawable)

before starting this didnt solve it :P

so basically i have a problem where my xml is : 
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_main_gradient" />
    <item android:gravity="center" android:drawable="@drawable/logo_splash"></item>
    <item  android:id="@+id/beTheSpeakers" android:gravity="center" android:top="50dp" android:width="200dp" android:height="30dp" android:drawable="@drawable/logo_splash_fadein" ></item>
</layer-list>
```

`
i would like to change the alpha of my second item. want to fade it in during the main launch of my android app.

However

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo_ampme);
        LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_launch);
```

does not seem to work .

has any1 been succesfull in replacing bitmaps which have been rendered or applying some sort of mask on them ?

thank you

Comment: why not just do an alpha animation on the drawable that you want removed?

Comment: i actually want to add an item like  a text appears first then another under it