# How to get the layer-list item ID in java class?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-drawable, layer-list

What method can I use to get the layer-list item ID
(**first_image**) in Java class?

layers.xml:

```
<item android:id="@+id/first_image">
  <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_red"
    android:gravity="center" />
</item>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change a layer-list drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018435/how-to-change-a-layer-list-drawable)

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically access item of `layer-list` by ID as given below.

```
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable
                .findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.first_image);
```